# How to use PrincipalContext with MVC Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory

I have a website in MVC .Net 3.5, I need to use the code below in a Controller. 
So I'm referencing the name space

`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

And I receive an error:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'DirectoryServices' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Which assembly Am I missing and how to add it in the project?

```
        // set up domain context
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        // find a user
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

        if (user != null)
        {
            // do something here.... 
            string givenName = user.GivenName;
        }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make sure you have added reference to the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll` assembly which is where this namespace lives.

For reference: [PrincipalContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Darin, I was able to add the dll using project reference. Many thanks